# Isolation Forest for Intrusion Detection System

Tags: python, scikit-learn, outliers, unsupervised-learning, anomaly-detection

I'm currently trying to use Scikit Learn to create a simple anomaly detection snippet.

The program receives a .csv file which then dissects into a Panda's DataFrame.
The Dataframe has 8 columns: 'Src IP'; 'Dst IP'; 'sPort'; 'dPort'; 'Protocol'; 'Load'; 'Packets'; 'TCP Flag'.

I fit the data into an IsolationForest like so:

```py
    iForest = IsolationForest(n_estimators=128, max_samples='auto', max_features=1, behaviour='new', contamination='auto', random_state=None, n_jobs=-1, verbose=0, bootstrap=True)
    usecols=["Src IP","Dst IP","sPort","dPort","Protocol","Load","Packets","TCP Flags"]
    iForest.fit(data[usecols])
```

And then get the Outliers/anomalies from the IForest:

```py
    pred = iForest.predict(data[usecols])
    data['anomaly']=pred
    outliers=data.loc[data['anomaly']==-1]
```

It all works well, however, my question here is:
How can I use Isolation Forest to detect anomalies on the network, while being independent on the 'contamination' property?

In an IDS, having a low False Positive rate is crucial. In my case i'm somewhat deciding what entries are 'contaminated' by choosing a percentage.

My goal is to make Isolation Forest set the contamination factor automatically, knowing that if x.csv is 100% clear of contamination, then find the % of contamination on y.csv.

This should be a part of an Hybrid IDS that uses both signature analysis and behavior to detect intrusions based on Flow Data (NetFlow).

**TLDR**: IsolationForest needs to receive a clean .csv (no contamination) to then detect anomalies on a new set of data (another .csv or pipe data). How is that possible using ScikitLearn?

Comment: It seems like sklearn is going to do precisely what you are asking for with the release of v0.22 where the contamination factor will have the option to be calculated automatically. Let's see how it's going to be!

Comment: @MaximeKan Thank you for your insight :) 
I was thinking wrongly from the beggining, in my use case I shouldn't be using Outlier Detection for detecting anomalies from a non-corrupted dataset but instead I should be using Novelty Detection.
In the Sklearn doc:
**outlier detection:**
  The training data contains outliers which are defined as observations that are far from the others.(...)
**novelty detection:**
  The training data is not polluted by outliers and we are interested in detecting whether a new observation is an outlier. In this context an outlier is also called a novelty.

Comment: I think what you're saying makes a lot of sense, it might be a more successful approach this way!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a training set which contains only normal data, then set `contamination=0`. To chose an appropriate threshold for anomalies, use a validation set and plot the histogram of anomaly scores. Without labeled data this can only be done heuristically:

For maximum True Positive (but sacrificing False Positives), set the threshold based on a budget of what resources you have for looking into Positives. You can compute this based on the inbound data rate, the expected Positives from the histogram statistics, and a cost (time/money) per evaluation.

For minimizing False Positives, set the threshold to be a bit outside the existing scores. The assumption is then that the training/validation contains practically no anomalies, and anything new and different is anomalous. Sometimes this is called novelty detection.

If it is possible to determine by looking at the data whether something was a true or false anomaly, I would recommend doing that for some 10-100 of the items with the highest anomaly score. This will usually be very fast compared to labeling all the data, and can help estimating the False Positive Rate.

When you put this model into production, your protocol for acting on anomalies should ensure that cases are evaluated and scored as anomaly/not. Then this is your future labeled validation/test data, which you can use to adjust the thresholds.

If you do have labeled anomaly/not anomaly in the validation/testset (but not in training), you can use this to optimize the threshold to maximize/minimize the desired metric using a hyper-parameter search.

Comment: There is no Labeled Data, hence the unsupervised approach. Still wondering what the best approach for unsupervised anomaly detection would be

Comment: You do not have to have labeled data, though without it you will have come up with a threshold without it. I have update the answer to reflect

Comment: I'm afraid that due to the scrutiny the project will receive, even if this is just a fraction of it, having an heuristic approach would be an easy target for criticism. This is an academic project.
What do you mean with histogram statistics? can it be automated?
Yes I've chosen a novelty detection approach, however, since the data is extremely volatile, the FP rates are enormous..

Comment: Better chose your threshold well then. Or label some data :)

Comment: @jonnor Thanks for your answer. May I ask you kindly to have a look at related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66643736/incorrect-results-of-isolationforest)?